# How to concatenate two columns with joined table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables `issue_details` and `payees` as shown below with values:

Table: **issue_details**

```
+----------+------------+----------+----------+
| check_no | issue_date | payee_id | lddap_no | 
+----------+------------+----------+----------+
|        0 | 2015-01-01 |          | 11101-15 | 
|        1 | 2015-01-24 |          | 11101-15 |
|    34561 | 2015-01-24 | 10       |          |
|    34562 | 2015-01-24 | 13       |          | 
+----------+------------+----------+----------+
```

Table: **payees**

```
+----------+--------------------+
| payee_id | payee_name         | 
+----------+--------------------+
| 1        | John Smith         | 
| 10       | Chen Lou           | 
| 11       | Mark Dello         |
| 12       | ANTRECCO           | 
| 13       | Shay Ridz          | 
+----------+--------------------+
```

I did this query to join two tables to describe the payee name in my `issue_details` table.

```
SELECT      
    issue_details.issue_date AS date,
    issue_details.check_no AS check_no,
    payees.payee_name AS payee 
FROM
    issue_details
INNER JOIN 
    payees ON issue_details.payee_id = payees.payee_id
```

**Result**:

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| check_no | issue_date | payee    | 
+----------+------------+----------+
|    34561 | 2015-01-24 | Chen Lou |       
|    34562 | 2015-01-24 | Shay Ridz|       
+----------+------------+----------+
```

If I do this:

```
SELECT      
    issue_details.issue_date AS date,
    issue_details.check_no AS check_no,
    CONCAT(payees.payee_name, '', lddap_no) AS payee 
FROM
    issue_details
INNER JOIN 
    payees ON issue_details.payee_id = payees.payee_id
```

The result is still the same above. It does not concatenate the two columns
of `payee_name` (joined from table payees) and `lddap_no`.

Here's what I want to happen:

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| check_no | issue_date | payee    |  
+----------+------------+----------+
|        0 | 2015-01-01 | 11101-15 |      
|        1 | 2015-01-24 | 11101-15 |     
|    34561 | 2015-01-24 | Chen Lou |
|    34562 | 2015-01-24 | Shay Ridz|     
+----------+------------+----------+
```

Please help with my query here. It would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()` to convert `NULL`s into empty strings.

Comment: how to use IFNULL() ? please show me how to put this in my query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      id.issue_date AS date,
            id.check_no AS check_no,
            COALESCE( p.payee_name, id.lddap_no ) AS payee 
FROM        issue_details id
            LEFT  JOIN payees p ON
            id.payee_id = p.payee_id
```

See [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31261/3)

Answer (score 0):

just change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT      issue_details.issue_date AS date,
            issue_details.check_no AS check_no,
            payees.payee_name AS payee 
FROM
            issue_details
            LEFT JOIN payees ON
            issue_details.payee_id = payees.payee_id
```